# External application remains frozen after modal window aborts

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm facing what seems to be Yet Another Windows Bug. I need to display a window that is modal to the main window of another application. The way I'm doing this, is by first getting the window handle of the other application's process:

```
var handle = Process.GetProcessById(appProcId).MainWindowHandle;
```

I then create an `IWin32Window` using that handle:

```
IWin32Window owner = new MyWindowHandleWrapper(handle);
```

(`MyWindowHandleWrapper` is a trivial implementation of the `IWin32Window` interface.)

I then create a form and show it modal over the `IWin32Window`:

```
var form = new ...
form.ShowDialog(owner);
```

This works like a treat if everything works OK. However, if the application that creates the modal form crashes, or is killed (from the task manager, for example), then the application window for which the form was shown modal on top of, remains frozen.

Is this really just another Windows brain damage that I need to live with, or is there something I can do about it?

I'm using .NET 2.0, VS 2010, Windows 7.

Comment: I suspect you're running into [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/07/10424279.aspx) - see the note at the bottom. No idea how to fix it though.